# When I take a mulligan, should I shuffle my library first?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mulligans

When I decide to throw away my hand and use a mulligan, should I simply draw a new hand from the library or shuffle my thrown hand into the library before redrawing? I'm mostly interested in [magic-the-gathering](/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering) mulligan rules, but I believe a "mulligan" isn't system-specific; I'd accept a well-sourced system-agnostic answer as well.

Comment: As a slight comment, a mulligan is game specific. Where in Magic you **have** to replace your entire hand with N - 1 cards (which is repeatable), for example [Hearthstone](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Mulligan) (Digital Card Game) allows you to swap up to N cards out for new ones, but only once. Both actions are called 'Mulligan' in the respective games.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Magic you always shuffle your hand into your library then draw a new hand.

> **103.4.** [...] To take a mulligan, a player shuffles his or her hand back into his or her library, then draws a new hand of one fewer cards than he or she had before. [...]

Comment: Of course if you're not playing in a sanctioned event, you can use whatever house rules you want.  For instance, some people still do the partial mulligan when they play EDH.

Comment: Forestalls the interpretation that you can choose to keep some of the cards, then mulligan the rest. It is a painful holdover from casual that I've seen pop up at FNMs with younger crowds.

Comment: @DrunkCynic It also is how mulligans worked in EDH until a few months ago, so if someone was coming from that perspective and hadn't heard of the rules change they could easily misinterpret it.

Comment: I must stress the word *always*.  Unless you're playing some house-rules-alteration or EDH, you must *always* mulligan this way.  This is non-negotiable at any sort of sanctioned MTG event.

Comment: Good terminology for not shuffling when mulliganing is "Lazy" mulligans. They are a common and good option for commander: a format not sanctioned for competitive play (only sanctioned for casual events).